# Searching name in string from list of names in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def get_name(string, list_names):
    """
    Inputs:
        string: a string to be analyzed
        list_names: a list of names among whom we are looking for
    """
    for name in list_names:
        begin_pattern = re.compile("^\name")
        if begin_pattern.search(string):
            return name
```

Hi I need search for names which I have in the string. My list is

```
 list_names = ['LaMarcus Aldridge',
     'Damian Lillard',
     'Wesley Matthews',
     'Arron Afflalo',
     'Robin Lopez',
     'Nicolas Batum',
     'Chris Kaman']
```

function returns no error but also it returns no matches at all.  `get_name("Damian Lillard makes 18-foot jumper (Allen Crabbe assists)", list_names)` it should return Damian Lillard. Can you help me. Thanks

Comment: In your method, list_players is not defined, unless it is globally outside your function.

Comment: yes i defined it globally outside as list_names as above. Oh sorry it should be list_names not list_players. I editted now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import re
def get_name(string, list_names):
    for name in list_names:
        match = re.search(r'\b%s\b'%(name),string)
        if match:
            return name

string ="Damian Lillard makes 18-foot jumper (Allen Crabbe assists)"
list_names = ['LaMarcus Aldridge','Damian Lillard','Wesley Matthews','Arron Afflalo','Robin Lopez','Nicolas Batum','Chris Kaman']

print(get_name(string,list_names))
```

Comment: i am using spyder. This function doesnt return anything, sorry. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @user5372470 Go to site [link](https://repl.it/) and choose python 3 and paste this code in editor and press run, i have run this code it returns matched name

Comment: If the string contains 2 of the names in the list, will it return both or just the first found?

Comment: I guess the question doesn't really contain enough information, on what is really wanted with the result. But since there is a list of names I assumed the goal was to return more than 1 name if multiple of the names in the list existed in the string.

Comment: I just noticed the comments in the other answer, where it seems the OP only wants to check the first 2 words in the string for the name. So I guess only 1 name is wanted, even if 2 names in the list might exist in the same string.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'm adding code in the spirit of what you want; ignore my original code.

```
def get_name(string,list_names):
    for name in list_names:
        if string.startswith(name):
            print(name)


list_names = ['LaMarcus Aldridge',
 'Damian Lillard',
 'Wesley Matthews',
 'Arron Afflalo',
 'Robin Lopez',
 'Nicolas Batum',
 'Chris Kaman']

get_name("Damian Lillard makes 18-foot jumper (Allen Crabbe assists)",   list_names)
```

Returns Damian Lillard. Or, if you wanted LaMarcus Aldridge, rather than changing your script, you'd use:

```
get_name("LaMarcus Aldridge makes 18-foot jumper (Allen Crabbe assists)", list_names)
```

According to your original question,

```
def get_name(string, list_names):
   for player in list_names:
    if player==string:
        return player


list_names = ['LaMarcus Aldridge',
 'Damian Lillard',
 'Wesley Matthews',
 'Arron Afflalo',
 'Robin Lopez',
 'Nicolas Batum',
 'Chris Kaman']

get_name('Damian Lillard', list_names)
```

Comment: i need to search name in the beginning of sentence not the name itself. So i need to see if first two words of sentence contains the name which is in my list.

Comment: `begin_pattern = re.match(r'\b%s\b'%(player),string)` this would return if it is in the beginning of string, so i used this. Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a simple `if x in y`, where it then checks if `x` exists in `y`. And if the string contains more than 1 of the names, you would need it to return a `list` of names. It is possible to use list comprehension like this:

```
def get_name(string, list_names):
    return [name for name in list_names if name in string]
```

Here is the same function without using list comprehension:

```
def get_name(string, list_names):
    results = []
    for name in list_names:
        if name in string:
            results.append(name)
    return results
```